# How to bind raw html in Angular2

Tags: angular

I use Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 and I want to create and bind some simple HTML directly. Is is possible and how?

I tried to use

```
{{myField}}
```

but the text in myField will get escaped.

For Angular 1.x i found hits for ng-bind-html, but this seems not be supported in 2.x

thx
Frank

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Bind to the `innerHTML` attribute

*There is 2 way to achieve:*

```ts
<div [innerHTML]="myField"></div>
<div innerHTML="{{myField}}"></div>
```

To mark the passed HTML as trusted so that Angulars DOM sanitizer doesn't strip parts of

```ts
<div [innerHTML]="myField | safeHtml"></div>
```

with a pipe like

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: i am using the same thing to prevent it from stripping the click event, but now the click event wont fire, i have seen other answers stating for a dynamic event click, but how do i make the click work in this simple situation mentioned above

Comment: You can't add anything Angular-specific using `[innerHTML]="..."` binding. The only way to make this work is to create and compile a component at runtime.

Comment: do you have any small example for this, that dynamic tab click example is way to much, i want to simply implement dynamic anchor links.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: Do you think if it is possible to do it within html like the following using Angular: 
in ts file:
HTMLstring = '<button type="button">a button</button>';

in HTML
<div [innerHTML] = "HTMLstring"> </div>

Comment: Sure, but if you also want to add `(click)="clickHandler()"` you're out of luck.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `<button> click <\button>` not rendering as button. any reason ? I'm getting code from .cshtml.

Comment: @k11k2 Did you check the link at the end of my answer?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what about function calling how can I achieve it like `(click)="clickHandler()"` any work around?

Comment: The plunker uses an old Angular version that didn't need and didn't have the santizer yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yea, edited my comment.

Comment: See my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842153/angular-2-innerhtml-input-binding. There is no way to accomplish that with `innerHTML`. You can add the HTML using `[innerHTML]="myHtml | safeHtml"` and then query for the element and use `addEventHandler` to add a click handler (like in plain JS)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2  angular way of event listen "NICE STUFF"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an update to the spec, but in Angular 5+, it is now DomSanitizer from @angular/platform-browser and not Sanitizer, which is an @angular/core class.

Comment: Looks like the safeHtml pipe should only be necessary / used in rare circumstances. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: @CRice depeds on what kind of app you write. If you want to buuld features thar depend on it, you don't have much choice. You should be aware that you can create security holes if you are nor careful.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes I agree, I just wanted to point this out so people think about it first and not just copy the pipe in all cases.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you know how do we render a html(which has properties binded) and make sure the binded values are displayed as a final output. Assume, we have these properties in the component which is rendering this html dynamicaly

Comment: There was a way to create a component dynamically at runtime where you could pass HTML with property+event binding. I don't know by heart where to find more details. I haven't used it myself. I don't think there is an easier way. There should be several questions about this topic here at SO.