# How can I convert strings of HTML into HTML in my template (Angular2/TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, templates, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have this object in a `dummy-data.ts` file. Through a service I pull it successfully in to `app.component.ts`.

```
{name:"Object1", 
    prop1: {key:'value', key:'value'},
    password: "P@ssword1",
    htmlText:'<h4>This is THE demo text</h4><p>I want it to display as HTML</p>'
}
```

Currently `app.component.ts` looks like this, to start out simply:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p *ngFor="#plot of plots">
            {{plot.personalPanelText.transition}}
        </p>
`,
providers: [PlotService]  
})
```

The end result is strings instead of HTML. I want the HTML to be code, not text with HTML tags.

I've tried a couple ways and poked around the world wide nets and Angular2 docs, but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see where you store your object therefore the code in my answer might not exactly fit your needs. Just add a comment or update your question with more details.

Comment: In JavaScript, HTML can only occur as strings. As such, I don't understand what you mean by *"The end result is strings instead of HTML. I want the HTML to be code, not text with HTML tags."*.

Comment: [Above solution is not loading inline html styles. Please check my answer here to load html with inline styles correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043342/7410456)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can bind to `innerHtml` like:

```
<div [innerHtml]="someProp.htmlText"></div>
```

Angular does not instantiate any components where the selectors that match tags or attributes in HTML added this way nor will it resolve any bindings (like `{{xx}}`)

See also [How to bind raw html in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585453/how-to-bind-raw-html-in-angular2/34585513#34585513)

Comment: if i want to convert htmlstring to html in component. how can i ?

Comment: @KetanAkbari Sorry, U don't understand your question. You can't add Angular components rhis way if that is your question.

Comment: I don't know `BsModalService`. I'd suggest to create a new question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can we convert string to html in `.ts` file?