# Html encoding in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I need your help with html encoding in angular 4.
I have some product records in database, with fullDescription field in this format:

```
&lt;div align="justify"&gt;&lt;span&gt;
```

Using `<div *ngIf="product" [innerHTML]="product.fullDescription"></div>` I'm getting the following output:

```
<div align="justify"><span>
```

as text.
Is this possible to render this as the innerHtml and not as text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your component's class, you can use HTML entity decoder function like this:

```
toHTML(input) : any {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
}
```

and in the template use:

```
<div *ngIf="product" [innerHTML]="toHTML(product.fullDescription)"></div>
```

Comment: I am also stuck with this issue. I have applied this process but so far no luck.

Comment: Inline styles present in string html content is not loading in Inner HTML content.

Answer (score 9):

***I have done it by implementing pipe.***

Create a component.ts file and in that file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml', pure: false })
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(data): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, data);
  }
}
```

*Then in app.module.ts:*

- import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from './pagecontent/pagecontent.component';
- add SanitizeHtmlPipe inside declarations[]

*Finally in component.html:*

```
<span [innerHTML]="data | sanitizeHtml"></span>
```

Thats it. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Above solution partially solved my issue. Along with above changes, below code changes helped me to load encoded string html with inline styles to div correctly.

Html code changes:

```
<div *ngIf="product" id="divFullDescription" #divFullDescription></div>
```

Angular component.ts side code changes:

```
@ViewChild('divFullDescription', { static: true }) divFullDescription: ElementRef;

loadHtml() {
    this.divFullDescription.nativeElement.innerHTML = 
        this.toHTML('&lt;div align="justify" style="color:red;"&gt;&lt;span&gt;');
}

toHTML(input) : any {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
}
```

I hope, this may help someone. Thanks!