# Set HTML space code in Typescript angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I just a problem about how to set space to my value in html.
I have code :

```
    setValuetoComboBox(test:string, lvl:number){
    let lastTest:string;
    let spaceString:string;
    //&#160;
    spaceString='&#160';
    for(var i = 1; i <= lvl; i++){
        spaceString=spaceString + '&#160';
    }
    lastTest = spaceString + test;
    return lastTest;
}
```

In this code, i have &#160 which to make space in html. and i have code in html:

```
                                    <select [formControl]="parent" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="-1">Root</option>
                                    <option value="{{test.id}}" *ngFor="let test of parentValue">
                                        {{setValuetoComboBox(test.name, test.lvl)}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
```

and the result is :

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLUNh.png)

this the wrong result, i want space not code &#160. Can anyone find the answer about my problem ?

Comment: Use `'  '` instead of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you actually want is

```
<option value="{{test.id}}" *ngFor="let test of parentValue"
    [innerHTML]="setValuetoComboBox(test.name, test.lvl)">
</option>
```

With `{{ }}` the literal string will be inserted.

You might need to mark it as secure using the sanitizer for example like shown in [How to bind raw html in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585453/how-to-bind-raw-html-in-angular2/34585513#34585513)

You should be aware that `setValuetoComboBox(...)` might be called very often (every time Angular runs change detection). It's usually a good idea to assign the results of the call in a property and bind to this property instead of binding to a function.

Binding to functions in the view is generally discouraged because of this. It can cause serious performance issues.