# Can't bind <img> tag in HTML content. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

Hello I am trying to bind an HTML string into my div it contains  tags too. Bold strings normal strings showing without any problem but my  tags coming as string.

I am using ng-bind-html with ngSanitize

```
<div flex style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:white" ng-bind-html="news_detail">

</div>
```

My HTML content is

```
<p>NBA'de sezon, Golden State Warriors'ın Cleveland Cavaliers'ı 4-0'la geçip şampiyon olmasıyla birlikte tamamlandı. Biz de her NBA takımının, geride bıraktığımız sezonda ne yaptığına dair ufak değerlendirmeler kaleme almaya karar verdik. Bugün, Atlantik Grubu'nu ele alacağız.</p><p>&lt;img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/&gt;</p><p><strong>Toronto Raptors</strong></p>
```

It is showing like this exactly

NBA'de sezon, Golden State Warriors'ın Cleveland Cavaliers'ı 4-0'la geçip şampiyon olmasıyla birlikte tamamlandı. Biz de her NBA takımının, geride bıraktığımız sezonda ne yaptığına dair ufak değerlendirmeler kaleme almaya karar verdik. Bugün, Atlantik Grubu'nu ele alacağız.

<img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/>

**Toronto Raptors**

How can I show img tags ?

Comment: is this the actual code? or the output? `<p>NBA'de sezon, Golden State Warriors'ın Cleveland Cavaliers'ı 4-0'la geçip şampiyon olmasıyla birlikte tamamlandı. Biz de her NBA takımının, geride bıraktığımız sezonda ne yaptığına dair ufak değerlendirmeler kaleme almaya karar verdik. Bugün, Atlantik Grubu'nu ele alacağız.</p><p>&lt;img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/&gt;</p><p><strong>Toronto Raptors</strong></p>
`

Comment: @aron9forever this is actual HTML content which I want to show in my div, stored in database as string

Comment: `&lt;img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/&gt;` I guess that's supposed to be `<img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/>` then

Comment: did you try [innerHTML] or safeHTML pipe? check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585453/how-to-bind-raw-html-in-angular2

Comment: @aron9forever that did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML string being pulled from your database has the `img` tags escaped so they are not being treated as HTML. You need to change the string to be properly written HTML, for example:

Old string:

```
<p>NBA'de sezon ...</p><p>&lt;img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/&gt;</p><p><strong>Toronto Raptors</strong></p>
```

New string:

```
<p>NBA'de sezon, ...</p><p><img src='http://i68.tinypic.com/2zoxmx3.jpg'/></p><p><strong>Toronto Raptors</strong></p>
```

Comment: $scope.replaced_content = $scope.news.text_content.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');$scope.replaced_content = $scope.replaced_content.replace(/\/&gt;/g, '>'); worked just fine