# Angular: filter pipe returns HTML

Tags: angular

I would like to highlight the words searched into a list , but the pipe returns the string without applying the css,instead 
of the yellow background  for the searched words it prints and shows the tag

```
<span class='highlight'>hello</span>
```

PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<any>, filter: any): any[] {
    if (!filter) return items;
    return items.filter(function(item){      
      if (item.desc.indexOf(filter) >= 0)  {
          item.desc=  item.desc(new RegExp(filter, 'i'),"<span class='highlight'>" + filter + "</span>");  
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
}
```

COMPONENT

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | FilterPipe: filter">                         
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div> {{item.desc}}</div>
</div>
```

STACKBLITZ

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4a4ga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
```

Comment: item.nombre =  item.desc. ...?

Comment: fix it thank you so much, but it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: [Filter pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), consider putting the logic directly into your component

Answer (score 1):

Try using `innerHTML` attribute

```
 <div   *ngFor="let item of items | FilterPipe: filter">                         
    <div [innerHTML]="item.nombre | safeHtml"></div>
   <div [innerHTML]="item.desc | safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

To mark the passed HTML as trusted so that Angulars DOM sanitizer doesn't strip parts 
with a pipe like

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585453/how-to-bind-raw-html-in-angular2)

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4a4ga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html